# MySQL JDBC does not behaves as the MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-workbench, syntax

I'm running the following from the MySQL Workbench, and from my local tomcat using jdbc.

```
START TRANSACTION;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `ROOT`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ROOT`.`all_tables` (
    `_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `class_type` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `schema` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `table_name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `server_id` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    `fields` VARCHAR(0) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `_id_UNIQUE` (`_id` ASC));
COMMIT;
```

It is a copy of query right before the execution which I compose in order to run via the jdbc which fails time after time with the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `ROOT`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ROOT`.`all_table' at line 2
```

So technically even if only execute the create table this fails with the same error, only line 1.

BUT, when I run the **same** query via the MySQL Workbench, it works wonderfully... time and time again!

Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the actual Java string that is sent to the database server? How do you construct it? Can we see that code?

Comment: I construct it using java string builder. With a whole lot of 'append'. Why does it matter how I create the string?

Comment: What Vérace said. If you pay close attention, your query line 2 is "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ROOT`.`all_tables` (" while the error says "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ROOT`.`all_table'": there's a missing backtick in the second version, plus the table names are different. Chances are you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Another extra comment: DDLs are atomic in MySQL, but they force a commit after its execution. Surrounding the two statements in a transaction is not going to work- you have to control the execution on the application manually. You are now doing: `START TRANSACTION; CREATE; [COMMIT]; CREATE; [COMMIT]; COMMIT;` Drop the `START TRANSACTION` and the final `commit`.

Comment: @watery I copied the query right before the execution, so this is the actual query. when I copy paste it to the workbench it works.

Comment: @jynus Also if I only execute the two middle lines, e.g. Create schema, and create table, it also failes on the same error but works on the workbench

Comment: Unrelated but: it doesn't make sense to start a transaction for DDL statements in MySQL. You can't roll them back anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that the Workbench is running your statements one at a time without you being noticed, while JDBC exactly sends to the database what you exactly ask it to send.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10804730/3127111), where a parameter is used on the connection driver to allow many SQL statements over a single JDBC statement object.

Comment: Good call... when I break it to two calls it works fine. Thanks.